# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)

Tags: php

i have made a function will return N-th digit of sequence number, example :

1234567891011121314151617

- The 5-th digit is 5
- The 20-th digit is 1

My function is like this

```
 <?php
   function getLength($number) {
   $length = 0;
   if ($number == 0){
      $length = 1;
   } else {
      $length = (int) log10($number)+1;
   }
     return $length;
  }
 ?>

<?php
 function getDigitNumber($digit){
   $number = 10000000000;
   $data = array();
   for($i=1;$i<=$number;$i++){  
   if(getLength($i) > 1){
     $array = str_split($i,1);
    for($n=0;$n<=count($array)-1;$n++){
        array_push($data,$array[$n]);
    }   
}else{
    $data[$i] = $i;
}
  } 
return $data[$digit];
}
?>
```

When i executed that i've a problem like this error message "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)". Maybe because i assign a large number in var `$number`

How can i fix that..or how can i make function that can handle these large number

thanks..

Comment: Why don't you convert the number to a string and use PHP's substr method?

Comment: Not to be mean, but wow...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> i have made a function will return N-th digit of sequence number,
>   example :
>
> 1234567891011121314151617
>
> ```
> The 5-th digit is 5
> The 20-th digit is 1
> ```

Why not:

```
$number[5];
$number[20];
```

The number has to be a string anyways, so just access the character with array syntax.

Comment: have u tried my code, u can change `$number` with low number like this `$number = 10;`?

Comment: then you will have to convert it first. for example: `number = 10; $sNumber = (string)$number; echo $sNumber[0];` outputs `1`

Comment: example $number=10; for($i=1;$i<=number;$i++){echo $i;} will output '12345678910', now from that i want get 5-th digit that will be return 5. the ilustrate is like that, a number not from string, but from loop.

Comment: then don't echo it, concatenate it to a string first: `for(...) {$s .= $i; } echo $s[27]` <-- outputs the 28st digit

Answer (score 2):

About the memory problem, it is indeed due to the large number:

```
$number = 10000000000;
$data = array();
for($i=1;$i<=$number;$i++){  
    if(getLength($i) > 1){
        $array = str_split($i,1);
        for($n=0;$n<=count($array)-1;$n++){
            array_push($data,$array[$n]);
        }
    } else{
        $data[$i] = $i;
    }
}
```

Basically, it allocates an array (`$data`) of ~500,000,000,000 items, which is *quite* big...

Manipulating your number as a string (or as a character array) as suggested in the other answers/comments will be: easier, more readable, faster, less memory-consuming, ...

Comment: can u give me an example how can i manipulate that to string, example `$number=10; for($i=1;$i<=number;$i++){// do something to convert as a string;}`?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with that loop. fab already gave you examples to get the n-th digit of a number: if you want to get the 3rd digit of `$number`, convert to a string via `$sNumber = (string) $number;` and `$sNumber[n]` will give you the n+1th digit

Comment: After reading more carefully your other comment, I get it. Yet, fab gave you another example for building the number you're trying to get the n-th digit from and for getting the n-th digit... I don't see what's unclear about it.